# How Can I write this equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am still new in latex...I have tried many times to write this equation in latex, but no way...always error...any help, please.

My Regards.

[image: Equation]

Comment: Yes, you can. And it is written in Tex, you know it and so do I. So put yourself to work and come back when you have something to show! Minimum effort is requiered in order to receive answers.

Comment: Did you hear about `mathmode`? The only troubling thing here could be the `\Bigg` brackets #hint   
You can look up the rest on the internet or draw the symbols on [kirelabs](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).  

People will also be much more likely to help you if you post your attempt which gives an error and the error itself.

Comment: Perhaps to apply the advice of Descartes: "
The second, to divide each of the difficulties that I would examine, into as many parcels as possible and that would be required to better solve them. " You can create intermediate variables and split your formula into simpler formulas. The expression will be easier to read.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
D_{ik}(t,\delta,C) = 
\sum_{c=0}^{\left[ \frac{\delta}{\tau}\right]}\Bigg(\displaystyle \prod_{r=1}^{e}  \bar{q}_{ic_n}^N(t.r) \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^{N} \bar{q}^{m-1}_{ic_j}(t,e)P_{ic_j}^{\tau_{ic_j}^m}(t,e)\\\nonumber
\big(\frac{L}
{\bar{\psi}^{\tau^{m}_{ic_j}}_{i{c_j}}(t)}+D_{cjk}(y,\delta)\big)+\sum_{e=1}^{\left[\frac{\delta}{\tau}\right]}\Big(\displaystyle\prod_{r=i}^{e}
\bar{q}^{N}_{ic_n}(t.r)e T(1-\bar{q}^{N}_{icn}(t,e)\Big)\Bigg)
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start. As explained in the above comments, what you want seems fairly easy to obtain, but I am too lazy to retype the whole thing :-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{D}_{ik}(t) = 
&\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \frac{c}{d} \rfloor} \Bigg( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \Big( \text{some stuff} \Big) \Bigg)\\
& + {} \text{some other stuff}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, brother Denis for your time and effort....I will try to complete the other parts...thanks again.

Comment: I'd prefer `\lfloor c/d\rfloor`.

Comment: @egreg Right. I was just trying to reproduce (part of) the example in which it seems that a `\frac` is used.

Comment: @Denis I liked how you give a starting point for the OP to have something to follow than doing all the work for them.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily Thanks for your comment. Giving a rough starting point is sometimes useful and does not prevent the OP from learning how to it, I hope.